# How do I search a nested Python dictionary for a matching dataframe value and then update the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, mapping

I have a Python dictionary with company information that is structured like this:

```
co_dict = {'0': {'co_name': 'A',
  'company_type': 'Public',
  'global_name': 'A PARENT',
  'sales': '1000'},
 '1': {'co_name': 'B',
  'company_type': 'Public',
  'global_name': 'B PARENT',
  'sales': '1000'}}
```

And a Pandas dataframe that looks like this (the real df is much longer):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'co-name': ['M','A','B','F'], 'co-number': [1,2,3,4]})

  co-name co-number
0    M     1
1    A     2
2    B     3
3    F     4
```

I would like to find matches for each df["co-name"] in the dictionary and append the corresponding dictionary values for "global_name" and "sales" to a new column in the df. When there is no match, the columns should both read "n/a". So the end result would look like this:

```
   co-name  co-number  global_name  sales
0   M          1        n/a         n/a
1   A          2        A PARENT    1000
2   B          3        B PARENT    2000
3   F          4        n/a         n/a
```

I tried to do this as follows:

```
def find_global_name(x):
    for key1 in co_dict.keys():
        if (x['co-name'] == co_dict[key1]['co_name']):
            return co_dict[key1]['global_name']
        else:
            return "n/a"
        
df['global_name'] = df.apply(find_global_name, axis=1)
```

But the for loop seems to stop after the first company "A" match. I'm stuck trying to figuring out why this. Why is this method not working? How do I accomplish this task? Many, many thanks for your help.

Comment: played a bit with your code. after it finds the first match, it breaks out (because you have a return key), so it cannot go back and search for B, or any other value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dataframe from the dictionary and merge with `df`:

```
(df.merge(pd.DataFrame(co_dict).T, 
         left_on = 'co-name',
         right_on = 'co_name', 
         how = 'left')
  .drop(columns=['co_name', 'company_type'])
 )
 
  co-name  co-number global_name sales
0       M          1         NaN   NaN
1       A          2    A PARENT  1000
2       B          3    B PARENT  1000
3       F          4         NaN   NaN
```

Your code can be much clearer and faster if you trim the dictionary to only the values you need, and combine with `map` which is quite fast ... this also allows you to avoid writing code that is probably not necessary.

Create dictionaries for the values you need:

```
global_name = {val['co_name']: val['global_name'] 
                         for _, val in co_dict.items()}

 sales = {val['co_name']: val['sales']
         for _, val in co_dict.items()}

 global_name
 {'A': 'A PARENT', 'B': 'B PARENT'}

 sales
 {'A': '1000', 'B': '1000'}
```

Map the dictionaries to the dataframe to create the new columns (the assumption here is that values in the column are unique; if not, this won't work and merge is a better option, as it can handle duplicates):

```
df.assign(global_name = df['co-name'].map(global_name), 
          sales = df['co-name'].map(sales))
Out[722]: 
  co-name  co-number global_name sales
0       M          1         NaN   NaN
1       A          2    A PARENT  1000
2       B          3    B PARENT  1000
3       F          4         NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Is there anyway to do it without converting the dictionary to a df and merging it the dataframes?

Comment: any reason why you dont want to convert to a dataframe?

Comment: The actual dataframe and dictionary I'm using are much bigger, and merging them just feels overwhelming. I only need a couple of the pieces of information in the dictionary at a time for each item in the dataframe. So I guess I assumed the dictionary method would be more workable? Or maybe I should be setting up a relational database between the two datasets some other way? Thanks for your help with this. Really appreciate it. I'm new to coding and have just gotten stuck with my project on this step.

Comment: I'm also confused more broadly as to why the dictionary method I tried above is stopping after the first dictionary item, and would like to understand why. Thanks.

Comment: left a comment on why I think your code does not go beyond the first match; also made some edits with another solution